# User Registration Form with Sprout Forms

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I try to implement a User Registration Form with Sprout Forms for hours, but it doesn't work ...

I have replaced the value for the action from "sproutForms/entries/saveEntry" to "users/saveUser".

How should I create the fields (username, password, email, first name, last name), that the user are stored.

In a further step, I will add custom fields for the users.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Sprout Forms to create users on your website. Take a look at the [Craft documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I know, but with Sprout Forms it is easy to add custom fields (I need about 20), field validation and integrate Sprout Email for diverse event notifications.

Comment: You can add all those fields to the user fieldset and mark them as required. What event notifications do you need?

Comment: E.g. send email to admin after change user fields or after send an event registration form

Answer (score 0):

It's on our list to explore supporting this feature but I do not think it is possible to do this yet.

At the time of this post, while Sprout Forms supports [Payload Forwarding](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/payload-forwarding) (and would let you set the submission URL to be `users/saveUser`) and allows you to customize your templates via [Template Overrides](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/template-overrides) (where you could ensure the submitted fields fit the proper format for Craft's User Registration such as the fields `username`, `email`, and `password` being used as the input name values for the fields they are associated with and the custom fields are wrapped in the `fields[]` namespace for their input names).

However, there are a handful of other situations that arise that will need to get sorted out before this works. For example, Craft throws an error when you try to save a field with the name `username` citing that it is a reserved word and Sprout Forms validates the submitted fields against the Form Model's validation rules, so you're probably not going to be able to submit the username field properly.